# Processing speed makes no difference in C program

Tags: c, multithreading, gmp, sqrt

I'm programming a tool that generates some digits of the square root of 2. The library I'm using is GMP to achive more digits. I debugged the program on a dual core with 1.4Ghz and on a quadcore with 3.4Ghz. Also I measured the time with the time(0) function which I used before the function call and after and then I substracted the result. I noticed that there is completely no difference in time when I try the program on different PC's with different CPU's. Maybe I need to enable something like multithreading or that it uses full power of the CPU. I should also mention that everything was compiled with GCC with the linker flags -lgmp.

Here is the code

```
/*
 * sqrt2.c
 *
 *  Created on: 18.02.2015
 *      Author: iPh1ps99
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#include "helper.h"

/*
 * @param decimals: Holds the amount of digits
 * @return Returns the malloc'd string holding the digits
 */
char *sqrt2(unsigned long decimals) {
    mpf_t result;
    mp_exp_t exp;
    char *output;

    /*
     * Initializing
     */
    mpf_set_default_prec(decimals * BINARYLOG10);
    mpf_inits(result, NULL);

    /*
     * Calculation
     */
    mpf_sqrt_ui(result, 2);

    /*
     * Converting number to a string
     */
    output = mpf_get_str(NULL, &exp, 10, 0, result);

    /*
     * Cleaning up
     */
    mpf_clears(result, NULL);

    return output;
}
```

And here is how I call the function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "helper.h"

int main() {
    unsigned long decimals = 100000000;
    char *output = NULL;
    FILE *out = NULL;
    out = fopen("sqrt2.txt", "w");
    if (out == NULL) {
        printf("Error occured while opening file!");
        return 1;
    }

    int start = time(NULL);
    output = sqrt2(decimals);
    int end = time(NULL);
    fprintf(out, "%.1s.%s\n", output, output + 1);
    printf("It took me about %d seconds to calculate %lu decimals\n", end - start,
            decimals);

    fclose(out);
    free(output);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So how many seconds does it take to run your program?

Comment: @nwellnhof Is that relevant because I didn't write it down... On both the exact same time atleast

Comment: You're measuring time as an integer ... What's the ballpark here? In real code a difference between e.g. 1.1 seconds and 1.9 seconds would be major, but you'd just see them as "1".

Comment: @unwind You are right but that wouldn't matter anyway because there is no difference to me if it's 55 or 54 seconds.

Comment: @iPh1ps99 But you refused to say what the actual value was, so I should I know that it's almost a minute? If it had been 1.1 vs 1.9, your code would be almost twice as fast on the faster CPU.

Comment: One possibility is that the execution time of your code is limited by memory bandwidth.

Comment: @unwind I can give you other irrational numbers and there I have values. I managed amount digits so that it matters about seconds and not about milliseconds.

Comment: @nwellnhof So there's no way to fix that, right?

Comment: *If* main memory bandwidth is the limiting factor, you could only try to find a more cache-friendly implementation of arbitrary-precision sqrt.

Comment: @nwellnhof may be right : on my Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU   P7350  @ 2.00GHz and memory DDR2 @800MHz, Data Width: 64 bits, it took 199s (and 117s if i shut down tv...). Type `cat /proc/cpuinfo` to know more about your processor and `dmidecode --type memory` to know more about memory

Comment: @francis Hmm I've got 2x 2GB DDR3@1600Mhz, the other one 2x 8GB at same frequency

Comment: Hence, it seems that the explanation of @nwellnhof is the right one  :  computing a large number of digits of `sqrt(2)` requires a large memory bandwidth. And comparable memory bandwidths (roughly frequencies...but much more complex, account for latency...) lead to similar execution time.

Comment: profile, profile, profile. How much time is spent computing digits, and how much time is spent converting digits to printable? Multiple cores don't matter for the serial parts of your program (Amdahl's Law), including I/O -- and traffic between the CPU and memory counts as I/O.

Comment: @mpez0 Tried that too. I changed the time measurement for just measuring the calculation. That doesn't differ much though and it's still the same on the other PC

Comment: If I recall correctly, GMP doesn't exploit multithreading for its algorithms. Did they add such functionality in the mean time? (I really doubt it)